# Why does PG claim that the INSERT query was successful when it was not actually?

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have this in a loop:

```
INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Even if there is a conflict (duplicate record) and the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` rule activates, it seems to return a "it worked" signal.

Should it not return a "it failed" signal? I bet you're gonna say that technically, the query "succeeded", but it did not insert any record because there was a conflict, so is that not a failure?

Comment: What signal are you talking about?  The command completion tag does differ.

Comment: The whole point of the `on conflict` clause **is** to prevent an error condition. If you want to check if it did insert rows, check the number of inserted rows reported by the statement.

Answer (score 4):

It didn't fail though, because you specified `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;`. The query succeeded in not doing anything since you instructed what it should do in a graceful manner when there is a data conflict. This is logically no different than using a try / catch in an object oriented programming language to gracefully capture an exception and swallow it as opposed to it being thrown as unhandled in the application.

If you want the query to fail on data conflicts, then don't gracefully handle it and remove the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;` clause.

For further information, please see the [`INSERT` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) specifically the "ON CONFLICT Clause" section where it states:

> The optional ON CONFLICT clause specifies an alternative action to raising a unique violation or exclusion constraint violation error.